# How to get the selected multiple values from checkbox and submit them in a form to get the matched search results

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This form contains a dropdown list that has multiple options with checkboxes, now when a user selects 1 or more checkboxes and presses submit, the values should be processed with the matching search results. Previously, I had a `select` tag with an `option` tag that was used to get the results. Now, since I added the functionality of searching for more than one option, I added checkboxes, but now I am not sure how to get the results.

Html and Php Code

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="ajax-search-form leaders-header" id="searchform" method="post" role="search">
        <?php get_template_part( 'blocks/leaderboard/search-form' ) ?>
        <div class="sort">

        <body>
        <?php if ($departments = get_field_object('field_5da06da87ae0f')) : ?>
        <div class="sort-item">
        <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
            <span class="anchor" style="font-size: small">All Departments</span>
            <ul id="items" class="items" name="department" >
                <label for="test">
                <?php foreach ($departments['choices'] as $key => $department) : ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="test" value="unchecked" /> <option style="font-size: small" <?php if ( isset($_REQUEST['role']) and $_REQUEST['role'] == $key) echo 'selected' ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>">

                        <?php echo $department; ?></option></label></br>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <input style="font-size: small" type="submit" value="Submit" "/>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
            var items = document.getElementById('items');
            var isChecked = document.getElementById('items').checked;
            checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
                if (items.classList.contains('visible')){
                    items.classList.remove('visible');
                    items.style.display = "none";
                }
                else{
                    items.classList.add('visible');
                    items.style.display = "block";
                }

            }

            items.onblur = function(evt) {
                items.classList.remove('visible');
            }


        </script>
```

Comment: Why do you have an `<option>` element outside of a `<select>` element? You may want to get a handle on what your HTML is supposed to look like before you try to build it with PHP. And you'd be much better served using a DOM library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that every checkbox will have the same name and id so you will be not able to recognize which option belongs to which checkbox but you can try something like this

```
<?php foreach ($departments['choices'] as $key => $department) : ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $department ?>" id="<?= $department ?>" value="unchecked" />
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, this aligns the dropdown but the functionality still doesn't work when we click submit.

Comment: Can you send the PHP method which is executed by this form?

Comment: `<?php if ( $users = get_users_for_leaderboard( $_REQUEST ) ) : ?>
  <div class="load-more-holder">
   <?php include( get_template_directory() . '/blocks/leaderboard/leaders-list.php' ); ?>
  </div>
 <?php endif ?>`